# Same users and profile table for multiple apps

Tags: laravel-5

I have three different apps for which i want to use the same login and profile. Which means if a user updates his profile information or changes his password that has to be updated in all the apps.

Currently im using a single database for all the three apps, but not sure if this is the right way. I checked few sso solutions, but not sure how to make profile table same for all the three apps.

The reason i want profiles table same for all the three apps is because the apps belong to the same industry(healthcare). If a doctor updates his information on one app, that has to be updated in all the three apps so that his information stays same on all the apps.

I'm currently using laravel 5.6 as the backend api and vuejs as the frontend with JWT login

Comment: The easiest solution is to build a single API. In that case, you have only one application in the server side. Create three different client side applications for the users.

Comment: @AbhishekReddy Currently im planning to create one central api and other apps(be it in medical, legal or fashion) that im planning to add, use the same database. Is this the right way to do it as im not good at sso and other things

Comment: There is nothing wrong. Make sure you put good design patterns to use to make sure the code doesn't confuse you later.

Answer (score 0):

I am late, but thought would help people looking for answers.

**1- Using Different API/Service for authentication**

As mentioned in the comments it is a good way to create a separate service for authentication. Could create an OAuth server for that purpose.

**2 - Using same Database**

It can be done is using similar `APP_KEY` for three applications. It is generally not a recommended way to use same app key for multiple apps, but in this case as three apps works as one and uses same database dont see a much problem with that.

To do so copy the app key from the main application's .env file to other 2 applications `.env` files. This is because app key is used in the process of encrypting the password when registering the user and logging in. So, it should be similar in all apps for the hashes to match. This way same database and same users table could be used.